# How to write log.info() to console in django using gunicorn?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have configured Django logging to print to console as well as log file. When I use `python manage.py runserver`, it works.

But, when I run this using `gunicorn` as `gunicorn app.wsgi:application`, `print` statement goes to console, but `log.info()` doesn't go anywhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the logger class name of your `log`?

Comment: @iMom0 You mean this `logging.getLogger(__name__)` or this `'class':'logging.StreamHandler'`?

Answer (score 3):

It is working now, I don't know how...

My `settings.py` section:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,

    # How to format the output
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
    },

    # Log handlers (where to go)
    'handlers': {
        'null': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'django.utils.log.NullHandler',
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': PROJECT_ROOT + "/repackager.log",
            'maxBytes': 50000,
            'backupCount': 2,
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },
        'console':{
            'level':'INFO',
            'class':'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        },
        'celery': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': PROJECT_ROOT + "/celery.log",
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 100,  # 100 mb
        },
    },

    # Loggers (where does the log come from)
    'loggers': {
        'repackager': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers':['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level':'WARN',
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'WARN',
            'propagate': False,
        },
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'gunicorn.error': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'gunicorn.access': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['logfile'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'celery': {
            'handlers': ['celery'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}
```

`views.py`

```
# Logger
import logging    
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```